# Where should I put the variable in this exercise?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given this exercise, in which the endings of my printed sentences have to be the symbol/letter 'p'.
When I run this program, the result is this:
If I use number 9:

```
p q p q

p q p

p q 

p
```

2. As you can see, 'p' is always at the beginning of the sentence, but I want it to be always at the end. Something like this.

```
q p q p

p q p

q p

p
```

3. I think the variable 'a' has to be reduced by 1 each time. Although, I don't know where I'd put that.
   Here's the code.

---

```
number = int((input()+1)/2 - 1)

i = 1

while i <= number:

    a = number
    while a >= i:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            print("q", end = " ")
            a -= 1
        elif a % 2 == 1:
            print("p", end = " ")
            a -= 1
    print()
    i += 1
```

Comment: I fixed it for you. Check the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63962781/revisions) if you want to see what was changed.

Comment: `input()+1` should fail if you're using Python 3, since `input()` returns a string, and you can't add a string and an int. Are you actually running it with Python 2? If so, using `print` as a function should fail, so IDK what's going on here.

Comment: Purely from a logical perspective (ignoring the `input()` issue pointed out by @wjandrea ) if you want the first character output to vary then always starting the loop with `a=number` will always produce the same letter output. So you will have to vary the initial number by `i`, perhaps start with a=i (and adding 1 to a each loop)  or start with `a=number-i`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code (to work with python 3)

```py
input_num = int(input())
number = int((input_num + 1) / 2 - 1)


def print_line(line_length):
    if line_length % 2 == 1:
        # start with p
        letters = ['p', 'q']
    else:
        # start with q
        letters = ['q', 'p']

    for i in range(line_length):
        pos = i % 2
        # print the relevant letter
        print(letters[pos], end=' ')
    print()


for n in range(number, 0, -1):
    print_line(n)
```

I made a method that knows how to print a specific line.

It receives the `line_length` and it knows how to print p's and q's.

if the line length is odd, we need to start with p

- 1 - p
- 3 - p q p
- 5 - p q p q p
- etc..

If the line length is even, we start with q

- 2 - q p
- 4 - q p q p
- 6 - q p q p q p
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the number of lines you want to see is integers that sum to the input + 1. 1+2+3+4 = 10 = 9+1. There will be 4 lines, and on each line you want to keep track of the number of letter on that line. Using better variable names makes it easier to follow the code.

```
input = 9
n_lines = 1
i = 1
while i < input:
    i += n_lines
    n_lines += 1

for line_number in range(n_lines):
    number_letters = n_lines - line_number  # This will be number of letters: 4, 3, 2, 1
    for i in range(number_letters - 1):
        print("q", end="")
    print("p")
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [-1] to place 'p' at the end

Comment: Where? There are no objects that support indexing in OP's code.